# Date format changes to time only while converting dataframe to csv

Tags: csv, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe imported from json:

```
                    DateAndTime  TAGID  TagValue  UIB
5       2017-04-26 00:00:00.000    105     109.9  NaN
23      2017-04-26 00:01:00.000    105     123.8  NaN
41      2017-04-26 17:46:00.000    105     106.1  NaN
59      2017-04-26 00:07:00.000    105     108.3  NaN
77      2017-04-26 16:38:00.000    105     103.8  NaN
95      2017-04-26 16:39:00.000    105     103.7  NaN
113     2017-04-26 00:08:00.000    105     107.8  NaN
131     2017-04-26 10:42:00.000    105     108.0  NaN
```

the code:

```
df105.to_csv("ddf105.csv", index=False)
```

the created csv file has only time of minutes and seconds. Like this:

```
DateAndTime
00:00.0
01:00.0
46:00.0
07:00.0
38:00.0
39:00.0
08:00.0
42:00.0
36:00.0
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Your dates are the index, you passed `index=False` so they don't get written out, your column `DateAndTime` only contains time values hence the output

Comment: @EdChum, there is a mistake. Let me correct that.

Comment: what does `df['DateAndTime'].iloc[0]` show?

Comment: @EdChum, It shows this:  2017-04-26 00:00:00.000

Comment: what does `df.info()` show? What is the dtype of that column? It should work which indicates you have some other issue

Comment: @EdChum, it says object.

Comment: That means it's a string probably, how are you confirming that it's only writing just that column as your code shows it would write out all columns? How are you reading this csv afterwards?

Comment: @EdChum, its not writing the dateand time column only. i just gave the example of that column. Code is writing all the columns. I am just opening the csv file in Excel.

Comment: It looks like an issue with excel then, if you open the csv in a text editor is the full datetime visible? For instance because it's a string a space will be inserted between the date and time, it looks like it's clipping this in excel

Comment: @EdChum, No. i opened it in text editor. But only the minutes and seconds is visible.

Comment: does it work if you convert the column to a real datetime64? i.e. `df['DateAndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateAndTime'])` and then export? It shouldn't matter but your issue is weird as it should still work fine

Comment: @EdChum, Great. It worked. I was also confused about this issue.

Comment: Should I post this as answer?